# Why does my RSpec assertion work on one view spec and not another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a Rails app with an "Events" model, and in the 'spec/features' directory I have a 'list_events_spec.rb' file and a 'show_event_spec.rb' file.  The following 3 assertions crashed my RSpec tests when placed in the 'list_events' spec, but the tests passed when I placed the assertions in the 'show_event' spec.  The header, footer and aside are all partials which are rendered in the application.html.erb file.

The only thing I can figure is that Rails treats these 2 files differently based on their filenames, but I would expect the assertions to work regardless of the spec_file they're placed in, since they're rendered in the application.html.erb file.

Here are the assertions (filenames are "_header.html.erb", "_footer.html.erb", and "_sidebar.html.erb"):

```
it "has a header" do
  expect(page).to have_selector("header")
end

it "has a footer" do
  expect(page).to have_selector("footer")
end

it "has a sidebar" do
  expect(page).to have_selector("aside")
end
```

And here is the application.html.erb file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>EventsTdd</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'header' %>
    <%= render 'sidebar' %>
    <%= yield %>

  </body>
  <%= render 'footer' %>

</html>
```

And here is the RSpec error message:

```
Failures:

  1) viewing the list of events has a sidebar
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_selector("aside")
     Capybara::ExpectationNotMet:
       expected to find css "aside" but there were no matches
     # ./spec/features/list_events_spec.rb:53:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) viewing the list of events has a footer
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_selector("footer")
     Capybara::ExpectationNotMet:
       expected to find css "footer" but there were no matches
     # ./spec/features/list_events_spec.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) viewing the list of events has a header
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_selector("header")
     Capybara::ExpectationNotMet:
       expected to find css "header" but there were no matches
     # ./spec/features/list_events_spec.rb:45:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.8435 seconds
33 examples, 3 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/list_events_spec.rb:52 # viewing the list of events has a sidebar
rspec ./spec/features/list_events_spec.rb:48 # viewing the list of events has a footer
rspec ./spec/features/list_events_spec.rb:44 # viewing the list of events has a header

Randomized with seed 16198
```

Comment: Without knowing your actual file structure (e.g., where do those files live, etc.) it's difficult to help. Does it work *outside* of the spec, e.g., when you view those pages?

Comment: Do you have any before or after hooks in your rspec files? It is important to note what "page" might be referring to. It's possible that, in the list view, "page" is only referring to the partial rendered under "yield", not to the full page. In other words, there would be no reason for rspec to render the full layout if you're only testing the list functionality.

Comment: Before hooks- that's it exactly.  I called the 'visit' method in a before hook in the 'show_event' spec, but not in the 'list_events' spec.  So Rails must not have recognized what 'page' was when hitting the assertions in the 'list_events' spec.  Rookie mistake. :-) Thanks for your help!